# Cannot index a document due to seq_no+primary_term conflict since upgrade to spring-data-elasticsearch 5.x

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I've upgraded from spring-data-elasticsearch 4.x to 5.x and switched from REST high level client to Elastic's new client. Since then, I'm getting a lot of

```
org.springframework.dao.OptimisticLockingFailureException: Cannot index a document due to seq_no+primary_term conflict
```

errors in my tests for (at least for me) no apparent reason. I cannot figure out what changed and is now causing these exceptions. Am I missing some configuration here?

Edit: I think it boils down to some tests having a @BeforeEach and @AfterEach which both delete on an index via Query.findAll() and I think the before method is triggered while the index is still being updated by the after method which for some reason didn't happen with the old client because ... the new one is just faster? Idk

The following code simulates such behaviour and (at least for me) reliably fails on the second delete:

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.testcontainers.service.connection.ServiceConnection;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Setting;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchOperations;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.mapping.IndexCoordinates;
import org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Query;
import org.testcontainers.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchContainer;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Container;
import org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.Testcontainers;
import org.testcontainers.shaded.org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils;

import lombok.Data;

@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
class RandomTest {

    @Container
    @ServiceConnection
    private static ElasticsearchContainer elasticsearchContainer = new ElasticsearchContainer("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:8.7.0");

    static {
        elasticsearchContainer.getEnvMap().put("xpack.security.enabled", "false");
    }

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchOperations;

    @Test
    void test()  {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            final TestDocument testDocument = new TestDocument();
            testDocument.setContent(RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(32));
            elasticsearchOperations.save(testDocument);
        }

        elasticsearchOperations.delete(Query.findAll(), TestDocument.class, IndexCoordinates.of("test-*"));
        elasticsearchOperations.delete(Query.findAll(), TestDocument.class, IndexCoordinates.of("test-*"));
        elasticsearchOperations.delete(Query.findAll(), TestDocument.class, IndexCoordinates.of("test-*"));
    }

    @Document(indexName = "<test-{now/d}>")
    @Setting(useServerConfiguration = true)
    @Data
    public static class TestDocument {
        private String content;
    }
}
```

We have several tests that have an @AfterEach cleaning up added data which tend to fail. Adding a Thread.sleep(1000) after the delete operation 'fixes' them but I still don't understand why that problem only arises with the new client.

Final edit: The issue is that with spring-data-es 4.4, ElasticsearchOperations#delete had a completely different behaviour to that of 5.1, it sent a lot of additional parameters by default, including conflict=proceed which just skips the now occuring issue. I don't know why anyone would completely change the underlying, invisible behaviour of an otherwise unchanged API but ok.

Comment: What you are missing is posting relevant configurations, code or a minimal reproducible example.